# How do I convert a string to an address?

Tags: c++, string, qt, casting, int

```
int qs = 465;
std::ostringstream os;
os << &qs;
QString tt = QString::fromStdString(os.str());
qDebug() << &qs; // output: 0x28fda8
qDebug() << tt; // output: "0x28fda8"
int *pp = tt; // how can i do this?
```

I know it's stupid but i want to try to do this

Comment: Basically you just need to convert your string to an integer, do you know how to do that?

Comment: `QString` and `int *` are not related so this conversion makes no sense (though it is possible). This actually seems to be XY problem. You should state what are you actually trying to achieve. Are you trying to convert address to `qs` stored in string into actual pointer?

Comment: What do you want `int *pp = tt;` to do? `tt` is a `QString` and doesn't fit in a `int *`. You can grab a pointer sized chunk out of `tt` and store it in `pp`. You could also let `pp` point to `tt`. The problem is both is undefined behavior because you are only allowed to point to objects that actually exist (and 1 behind existing objects) of the correct type. You can do `void *pp = &tt;` to just store the address of `tt` in `pp` without UB.

Comment: I was just lurking here for past 5 minutes and thinking of an answer. Isn't this about converting a string to hex? P.S: I am most stupid and proud :)

Comment: @Stefan `tt.toInt(r, 16)`, but it's still not an address and i cant do `int *pp = tt.toInt(r, 16)`

Comment: @nwp That `QString` contains an address of `int` variable and i want to assign that address to another pointer. It's similar to `int i = 3; int *p = &i;`

Comment: Ah, now I get it. You want to turn an `int *` into a `QString` and then back into an `int *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't. But if you really must you could capture the value of an address and cast it to `int*`. A real messy way would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    int qs = 465;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << &qs;
    std::uintptr_t temp;
    ss >> std::hex >> temp;
    int* pp = reinterpret_cast<int*>(temp);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't convert the string back to an `int *`.

Comment: @nwp actually it does

Comment: @МишаковМаксим You're right, I missed it. The detour with `temp` is unfortunate but totally valid.

Comment: I would prefer using `std::uintptr_t` instead of `std::size_t`. Former is guaranteed to be big enough for a data pointer; latter is not.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Ron

```
int qs = 465;
std::ostringstream os;
os << &qs;
QString tt = QString::fromStdString(os.str());
qDebug() << &qs; // output: 0x28fda8
qDebug() << tt; // output: "0x28fda8"
bool *r;
int* pp = reinterpret_cast<int*>(tt.toInt(r, 16));
qDebug() << *pp; // output: 465
```

Comment: `int` is not necessarily big enough to represent a data pointer.